# Lazy for comprehension evaluation in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, immutability, lazy-evaluation, for-comprehension

I'm new to scala and most functional languages and I'm currently trying to factor a number.  i've written the code:

```
lazy val factors = for(int <- 2 until  math.ceil(math.sqrt(number)).toInt if number%int == 0) yield int
```

I was wondering If I declared the scala val as lazy will it not evaluate the entire for comprehension when I call `factors.head`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `factors` variable is lazy; the `for` comprehension isn't. When you access `factors` the first time, your `for` comprehension will be fully evaluated.

In Scala, `for` comprehension is merely a sugar for `flatMap`, `map`, and `withFilter` method calls. So if your backing data structure is strict (such as `Range` - which is what you are using), your `for` comprehension will also be strict. If the data structure is lazy (such as `Stream`), so will be `for` comprehension.

Observe the difference:

```
scala> val number = 50
number: Int = 50

scala> lazy val factors = for(int <- 2 until  math.ceil(math.sqrt(number)).toInt if number%int == 0) yield int
factors: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = <lazy>

scala> factors.head
res5: Int = 2

scala> factors
res6: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 5)

scala> lazy val factors = for(int <- Stream.range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(number)).toInt - 1) if number%int == 0) yield int
factors: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = <lazy>

scala> factors.head
res7: Int = 2

scala> factors
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(2, ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

No. It is a completely different thing: `lazy` means that the value is computed the first time you access to it. If you want lazy computation for collections, you should use [`Stream`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream) or use a view. A `Stream`can be built from a collection using `view`.